# excel function to vba code (exclusive quartile & if function)

Tags: excel, vba, quartile

I am trying to get this piece of excel function into vba code (mainly because there is no such thing as "application.worksheetfunction.if" - would be great if i can get some help here!

```
=quartile.exc(if((F:F=F2)*(Y:Y=1),I:I),1)
```

basically, i wanted to find the 25th percentile of all data in column I if two criteria are met: 1) if value of column F is the same, 2) if column Y value = 1. Otherwise return to blank.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure why the downvote and close-vote, this is a perfectly valid question , if poorly phrased.

Comment: Hmm, actually, the poor phrasing came from the spurious editing, which I have rolled-back.

Answer (score 2):

If that formula gets you the answer you want, then you could simply use:

```
Activesheet.Evaluate("=QUARTILE.EXC(IF((F:F=F2)*(Y:Y=1),I:I),1)")
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly!! - was just thinking if there's a way to have it runs faster? I'm looping this with a very large datase and it is taking a considerable amount of time :)